# solving differential equation with variable coefficients: $u''-e^{t}u'-e^{t}u=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the following second order differential equation with variable coefficients:
$u''-e^{t}u'-e^{t}u=1$

I just don't know how can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Is $u$ a function of $t$?

Comment: yes it is u(t).

Comment: Please do find out where I am wrong, or else this really has no closed form.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that: $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}e^t\cdot u=e^tu+e^tu'$$

Therefore, the question becomes: $$u''-(e^tu)'=1$$

Using addition law: $$(u'-e^tu)'=1$$

Integrating both sides: $$u'-e^tu=t+C\tag{1}$$

Now, we observe that: $$(ug)'=u'g+g'u=\frac1g\left(u'+\frac{g'}gu\right)\tag{2}$$

To find a suitable $g$, we compare, and find out that: $$\frac{g'}g=-e^t$$

Then: $$\frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dt}=-ge^t$$

Separating $g$ and $t$: $$-\frac1g\mathrm dg=e^t\mathrm dt$$

Integrating both sides: $$-\ln|g|=e^t$$

Making $g$ the subject: $$g=e^{-e^t}\tag{3}$$

Back to $(2)$: $$u'-e^tu=g(ug)'$$

Back to $(1)$: $$g(ug)'=t+C$$

Substituting $(3)$: $$e^{-e^t}(ue^{-e^t})'=t+C$$

Then: $$(ue^{-e^t})'=(t+C)e^{e^t}$$

Now the integral of right hand side **has no closed form**. Let the integral of $e^{e^t}$ be $F(t)$ and that of $te^{e^t}$ be $G(t)$.

Then: $$ue^{-e^t}=G(t)+CF(t)+D$$

Finally: $$u=e^{e^t}(G(t)+CF(t)+D)$$
where $C$ and $D$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Nice, but you don't need the constant $D$. After all, you only need a single function $g$, not the general such function.

Comment: https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Hanche-Olsen :o

Comment: Why do we only need a single function $g$?

Comment: Yeah thats me. 8-) Why only a single $g$? You practically said so yourself: “To find a suitable $g$, …” It's just an auxiliary function you introduced in order to proceed. *Any* function satisfying the differential equation you derived for it will do. Also, you might note that though it looks like your final solution has three independent constants, there are in reality only two. As there *should* be, for a second order ODE.

Comment: Ok, thanks :)))

Comment: One more thing: You can express your answer in terms of the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral); more precisely, in terms of $\operatorname{Ei}(-e^t)$, if my calculations are correct.

Comment: This one still cannot be done, because it is multiplied by the variable.

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of partial integration.

Comment: I tried wolframalpha.

Comment: Um, yeah, you'd need to integrate $\operatorname{Ei}$ itself. My bad.

Comment: I would write the integral in the second integration as $F(t)+CG(t)$ where $F$ and $G$ are both nonelenentary functions (perhaps expressible with the $Ei$ function based on other comments).  Then we have a general solution properly showing two constants of integration.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks, edited accordingly.